# Data shuffles in ListView android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on a listview in android xamarin. I have created a custom control with a webview, radiogroup and 3 radio buttons. I have an html string which is split to create an array of questions which is passed to the adapter.Which binds them to the ListView as shown in the screen shot.

The problem is whenever i scroll the screen, either the data gets jumbled, the rows get jumbled. Say i have 5 questions, in order A,B,C,D,E - it may become D,B,C,D,E or E,B,C,D,E or A B E D C randomnly. Not sure Why on earth this should happen. Tried few things but it just won't work.

And I am using the Fragments for the screen as i have other screens as well which update a data object , that is later submitted to a server.

[image]

I am sure there is something wrong with the code in Adapter class but not able to figure it out. Here's the code (**The commented code is the old code which i had tried.)

Updated GetView Code

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                //var view = convertView ?? _activity.Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.SegmentedControl, parent, false);
                View view = convertView;
                ViewHolder holder = null;

                Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("position - " + position + " dsadsadsadad - " + _questionList [position]);
                //if (view == null) {
                /*if (view != null) {
                    view = null;
                }*/
                view = _activity.Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.SegmentedControl, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder ();

                holder.WebViewQuestion = view.FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.segmentControlQuestionTextView);
                //holder.RadioGroupToUse = view.FindViewById<RadioGroup> (Resource.Id.segmentControlRadioGroupLayout);
                holder.RadioButton1 = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.segmentControlRadio1);
                holder.RadioButton2 = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.segmentControlRadio2);
                holder.RadioButton3 = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.segmentControlRadio3);

                //holder.RadioButton1.CheckedChange += ((object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) => {
                holder.RadioButton1.Click += ((object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                    //if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked) {
                    //Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("Choice is : A ==== " + _questionArr [position]);
                    _activity.Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                        holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                        holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,255,0,255));

                        holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                        holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,0,0,255));

                        //(sender as Button).SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.LimeGreen);
                        (sender as Button).SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.GreenButton_BlackBorder);

                    });
                    Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("Choice is : A ==== " + _questionList [position].QuestionText);
                    UpdateFeedback2Answer3String (position, 0, false);
                    //}
                });

                //holder.RadioButton2.CheckedChange += ((object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) => {
                holder.RadioButton2.Click += ((object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                    //if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked) {
                    //Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("Choice is : B === " + _questionArr [position]);
                    _activity.Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                        holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                        holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(0,255,0,255));

                        holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                        holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,0,0,255));

                        //(sender as Button).SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
                        (sender as Button).SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.YellowButton_BlackBorder);

                    });
                    Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("Choice is : A ==== " + _questionList [position].QuestionText);
                    UpdateFeedback2Answer3String (position, 1, false);
                    //}
                });

                //holder.RadioButton3.Click += ((object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) => {
                holder.RadioButton3.Click += ((object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                    //if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked) {
                    //Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("Choice is : C === " + _questionArr [position]);
                    _activity.Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                        holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                        holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(0,255,0,255));

                        holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                        holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,255,0,255));

                        //(sender as Button).SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
                        (sender as Button).SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.RedButton_BlackBorder);

                    });
                    Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("Choice is : A ==== " + _questionList [position].QuestionText);
                    UpdateFeedback2Answer3String (position, 2, false);
                    //}
                });
                view.Tag = holder;
                //segmentControlQuestionTextView = view.FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.segmentControlQuestionTextView);

                /*} else {
                    view = convertView;
                    holder = view.Tag as ViewHolder;

                }*/

                string html_string;
                html_string = "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body style='background-color: #50b983'>" +
                "<font face='ProximaNova_Regular' size='4' color='white'>{text}</font> " +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>"; 
                //html_string = html_string.Replace ("{text}", _questionArr [position]);
                Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("Current View : " + position);
                html_string = html_string.Replace ("{text}", _questionList [position].QuestionText);
                holder.WebViewQuestion.LoadData (html_string, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
                string feedback2Question3Answer = string.Empty;

                if (ChallengeFeedbackActivity.ReviewState) {
                    if (ChallengeFeedbackActivity.FeedbackToReview != null && ChallengeFeedbackActivity.FeedbackToReview != null) {
                        //SetFragmentData (ChallengeFeedbackActivity.FeedbackToReview.UserChallengeFeedbackResponse.Feedback2Question3Answer, position);
                        feedback2Question3Answer = ChallengeFeedbackActivity.FeedbackToReview.UserChallengeFeedbackResponse.Feedback2Question3Answer;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (AppData.Instance.FeedbackSubmissionData != null) {
                        feedback2Question3Answer =  Utils.IsStringNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace(AppData.Instance.FeedbackSubmissionData.Feedback2Question3Answer)
                            ?FeedbackSegmentedQuestionsFragment.Feedback2Answer3String:AppData.Instance.FeedbackSubmissionData.Feedback2Question3Answer;
                        //SetFragmentData (AppData.Instance.FeedbackSubmissionData.Feedback2Question3Answer, position);
                    } else {
                        feedback2Question3Answer = FeedbackSegmentedQuestionsFragment.Feedback2Answer3String;

                    }
                }


                if (!Utils.IsStringNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace (feedback2Question3Answer)) {
                    string[] ansarr = new string[feedback2Question3Answer.Split (',').Length];
                    ansarr = feedback2Question3Answer.Split (',');
                    switch (ansarr [position].Split (':') [1].ToLower ()) {
                    case "a":
                        _activity.Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                            holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.GreenButton_BlackBorder);
                            //holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.LimeGreen);
                            holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                            holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,255,0,255));
                            holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                            holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,0,0,255));

                        });

                        //holder.RadioButton1.Checked = true;
                        //holder.RadioButton2.Checked = false;
                        //holder.RadioButton3.Checked = false;

                        break;
                    case "b":
                        _activity.Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                            holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.YellowButton_BlackBorder);
                            //holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
                            holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                            holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(0,255,0,255));
                            holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                            holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,0,0,255));

                        });

                        //holder.RadioButton1.Checked = false;
                        //holder.RadioButton2.Checked = true;
                        //holder.RadioButton3.Checked = false;
                        break;
                    case "c":
                        _activity.Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                            holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.RedButton_BlackBorder);
                            //holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
                            holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                            holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(0,255,0,255));
                            holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                            holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,255,0,255));

                        });

                        //holder.RadioButton1.Checked = false;
                        //holder.RadioButton2.Checked = false;
                        //holder.RadioButton3.Checked = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.YellowButton_BlackBorder);
                        //holder.RadioButton2.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
                        holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                        holder.RadioButton1.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(0,255,0,255));
                        holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundResource (0);
                        holder.RadioButton3.SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color(255,0,0,255));
                        //holder.RadioButton1.Checked = false;
                        //holder.RadioButton2.Checked = true;
                        //holder.RadioButton3.Checked = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (ChallengeFeedbackActivity.ReviewState) {
                        holder.RadioButton1.Enabled = false;
                        holder.RadioButton2.Enabled = false;
                        holder.RadioButton3.Enabled = false;

                    }

                }

                return view;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is, just close your `if (holder == null) {` statement two lines down, so that it goes like this:

```
if (holder == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder ();
                    view = _activity.Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.SegmentedControl, parent, false);
}
```

That is the easy part (I hope), the reason you are having an problem is because views in a ListView get recycled (so that old values remain) but they are not alway recycled which is why you see it behave inconsistently. I suggest you read up on ListView view recycling. Here is [an article](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) I find helpful.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code i tried.  Take a look at it.Even that  didn't work. It would just shuffle the rows on scroll. In the end i just remove the if else part. It works, but at the cost of performance. How can i ensure that recycling is correct ?

Comment: i removed if(convertView == null){ ..}else{} part to not allow any reshuffle at the cost of performance. but i really need to know a better way to handle the issue.

Comment: I (and probably everyone) **strongly discourage** not using `convertView`. The way to overcome this issue is to remember to set **every** view that might change at any point to it's correct value. So, colors, textView texts and so on should be set (or re-set) on each getView call no matter if convertView is null or not.

Comment: i am already doing it. Take a look at the updated code above. If i put the null check it, still does the shufflling. I have to stick with NOT using convertview. :/